# Is there a better way to wire this?

Tags: electrical

I'm adding hardwired [edit: and interconnected] smoke detectors and replacing some knob-and-tube wiring. I'm using 14/3 wire on a 15a circuit, and 22 cu in boxes where new boxes are needed. The middle fan is a whole-house fan in the hallway; the others are ceiling fans in bedrooms. The lights are in the hallway and bathroom (I didn't show the bath fan, on the same switch).

The wiring seems overly complex, with the boxes close to full code capacity. Am I missing some more elegant way to route everything??
[image: hallway wiring]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's code in your area since this is a building code issue but new hard wired smokes must be interconnected. I'd venture to say it is code in most places.

This means you have to feed the smokes at any one, then run 3-wire between them. Typically the red wire is used as the interconnect wire. Some areas have requirements that say the smokes must be on a dedicated circuit, some say they must be on a local lighting circuit. The local requirements on this vary.

I hope you do not mean you are using only 14/3, but a mix of 14/2 and 14/3.

Also, I would NOT put the whole house fan on this general use circuit. No valid reason other than convention and to lessen the load on such a circuit.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by line and load in your diagram. That makes no sense as far as the diagram goes.

Comment: Yes, the 14/3 is for interconnecting the SDs/COs. I intended to use 14/3 everywhere, and just put a wirenut on the 3rd wire when not needed. Bad idea? Bulk pricing means it's much cheaper to do it that way than buy two shorter coils of two different wires. I believe LA county allows SDs to be on  a shared circuit with other fixtures, but I will double-check.

Comment: line is from panel; load is to another room with 3 new receptacles, 2 new SDs, and 1 new CO.

Comment: @PhilEsra, yeah, IMO it is wasteful and silly to use 14/3 everywhere. Also, NO WAY I'd buy smaller rolls of wire. Wire prices are not that high right now. Just get 250' of each, the price per foot is obscene in smaller rolls.

Comment: Yeah, I've got 250' of 14/3. Even if I only use 14/3, I will end up with way more left over than I will likely need over the next decade. Hard to see  adding 200 feet of 14/2 to the stockpile as a better approach.

Comment: @PhilEsra, then you'll be fine. Nothing wrong with capping off an unused wire. Better to have it and not need it than need it and not have it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback--appreciate it! The price gap between 100' and 250' is so weird. They really want you to buy that extra 150' even if they have to give it away.